# Could someone help me with this javascript code

Tags: javascript

Hello i was learning Javascript from 10 day of javascript videos and in last day it still runs error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertAdjacentHTML' of null

could someone help me

```
let ourForm = document.getElementById('ourForm')
let ourField = document.getElementById('ourField')
let ourList = document.getElementById('ourList')

ourForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    createItem(ourField.value)
})

function createItem(x) {
    ourList.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', x)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This will be because the element with an id of `ourList` does not exist. Double check you have an element in your HTML with this id.

Comment: yeah i checked and i find that i typed uorList instead of ourList

Answer (score 3):

Please recheck your HTML code. It looks like you missed the id `ourList` somewhere. The error means that your javascript was unable to find the element with the given id.

Comment: yeah i checked and i find that i typed uorList instead of ourList

Answer (score 2):

If you check your HTML code, there must be an element with an id of "ourList" for your code to work. Since the error says that an object with that id currently returns a null, something is incorrect. You most likely either misspelled it, or forgot to add the id to the corresponding HTML element.

You do this by writing:

`<ul id="ourList"> ... </ul>`

where `ul` is your element type. (`ul`, `ol`, `div`...)